# Call a C# function using HTML onclick button

Tags: c#, html, razor-pages, buttonclick

I am working with asp.net(C#). I created a razor page and want to call a function in C# using the html button click. The function performs a matching algorithm similar to the stable marriage problem. For example, when the Admin clicks on button "Button1", the function matching() in C# has to be called, which should execute the statements within the function and return the matched list in the end. I have seen some generic answers in the form but I need something more specific. Thanks in advance

As mentioned, this is a matching algorithm- to perform a two-sided matching with one sided preference.
I have already tried the html "Button1_Click" solution.
this is very generic and doesn't go with my code.

this is what I have done so far:

html code:

```html
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <button type="submit" id="cmdAction" text="Button1" runat="server">
        Button1
    </button>
</form>
```

C# code:

```
public ActionResult OnGet()
{
if (NTUser.Role != Role.Admin)
{return RedirectToPage("/Denied");}
matching();
return RedirectToPage();
}    
public void matching()
{//body}
```

The button I am using on the html side is "Match and Show the result"

I expect the output to be a list like an excel sheet that can be edited/deleted if need be.

Edit:
I would also appreciate if someone has an idea how to do it with an enum and/or bool

Comment: For me, your code looks alright. Any exceptions?

Comment: Are you using `razor` syntex or plain html to call the `Action` on `Controller`? It will be more helpfull of you update your `View`'s code here

Comment: Seems to me that you are confusing Web Forms (`runat="server"`) with Razor Pages. They are two different, and incompatible, frameworks. If you are using Razor Pages and want to determine which button was clicked, use named handlers:https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/handler-methods#named-handler-methods

Comment: I am not trying to find out which button was clicked. I want to call a C# function on the server side when a button is clicked on the client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call one method where you check role and redirect on another action or just call a private method.

```
public ActionResult OnGet()
{
     if (NTUser.Role != Role.Admin)
     {
        return RedirectToPage("/Denied");
     }
     else
     {
        return RedirectToAction(Matching);
     }
      ...other if with return
}

public ActionResult Matching()
{
   //dosomething
}
```

**view**

if you need post then use it

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("OnGet", "YourControllerName", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <button type="submit" id="cmdAction" runat="server">
        Match and Show the result
    </button>
}
```

if you need just get

```
@Html.ActionLink("Match and Show the result", "OnGet", "YourControllerName") //without params
```

dont forget add attribute `[HttpPost]` or `[HttpGet]`(get just for better readability code)

Comment: This is on the C# side. But how will it be connected to the button on the html side?

Comment: Also, I have edited my question. So if you have any suggestions on that, they are most welcome

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("OnGet", "ControllerName"> Display Text</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to do this, since you'ver mentioned razor pages so i'll recommend go through this [guide](https://blog.michaelckennedy.net/2012/01/20/building-asp-net-mvc-forms-with-razor/)

Simply use razor syntax like this

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post)) { 
   <input type="submit" value="Match" />
}
```